# How to reduce the noise from a grey scaled image without openCV?

Tags: java

How does one reduce the noise in an image using cellular automata without the use of OpenCV?

Comment: Why can't you use OpenCV?

Comment: @AndyTurner, it was a project where we had to count the number of spots on an animal without the use of the OpenCV library. Reducing the noise of the image was a part of the process to find the spots. The main goal here was to add resources for if anyone else had to solve the same problem.

Comment: Did you consider a gaussian blur?

Comment: @mat555 so you can use any other library, just not OpenCV? Or you have to implement it yourself?

Comment: @AndyTurner The goal is to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the image has been changed to greyscale using BufferedImage, on can use the following to find the Neumann neighbourhood to then apply the Cellular Automata reduction. https://cs214.cs.sun.ac.za/projects/Popovici.pdf - Link to the noise reduction article.

```
public Color[] neumannNeighbourhood(int x, int y) {
    Color[] intensity = new Color[5];
    intensity[4] = new Color(greyPic.getRGB(x, y));
    intensity[0] = new Color(greyPic.getRGB(x, y - 1));
    intensity[1] = new Color(greyPic.getRGB(x + 1, y));
    intensity[2] = new Color(greyPic.getRGB(x, y + 1));
    intensity[3] = new Color(greyPic.getRGB(x - 1, y));
    return intensity;
  }
```

Once the neighbourhood has been found, one will then set up the variable for the new BufferedImage and an Auxiliary array to store the new values that will have been set to the image after the noise has been reduced.

```
    reducedPic = greyPic;
    Color[][] aux = new Color[width][height];
```

No need to reduce the noise of the edge pixels due to their only being 3 pixels that will be checked. The method of how the "intensity" of the pixel is found is in the PDF link above. This sets the auxiliary array to prevent changes being made to the address of the buffered image (greyPic). *This code can be optimised but this works.*

```
// going through the neighbourhood with the neumannNeighbourhood method.
    for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
      for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; y++) {

        Color[] intensity = neumannNeighbourhood(x, y);

        // Checking the duplicates
        Color dupRGB = intensity[4];
        int cDup = 0, max = 1;

        // Iterating through the neighbourhood.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
            if (intensity[i].getRed() == intensity[j].getRed()) {
              cDup++;
            }
          }
          if (cDup >= max) {
            max = cDup;
            dupRGB = intensity[i];
          }
          cDup = 0;
        }
        aux[x][y] = dupRGB;
      }
    }
```

Once the auxiliary array has been set, we apply the changes to the noise reduced buffered image.

```
 for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
      for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; y++) {
        reducedPic.setRGB(x, y, aux[x][y].getRGB());
      }
    }
```

To then save the image after the it has been processed if you'd like.

```
File out = new File("filepath");
    try {
      ImageIO.write(reducedPic, "png", out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Problem saving the image.");
    }
```

Comment: So it looks like your setting the pixel to the color that most occurs in the 4 pixel immediate neighborhood?

Comment: @matt Yes. From the Popovici article, there are different types of neighbourhoods (the Moore and von Neumann) and in this case, making use of the von Neumann neighbourhood. From the equation, it is taking the most occurred and if there is a tie, it takes the centre value over the other occurrence. This is the reason for the last value in the array to be the centre value. This solves the problem with tied occurrences.